# Create View displays differently than the select

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a view and the select statement is exactly what I want to see, but when I use that exact same select statement as the create view statement its parses the information differently. Here is the select statement.

```
CREATE VIEW shippingview
AS
(   SELECT shipcarton.id AS shipcartonid
            ,ship.num AS shipnum
            ,so.num AS sonum
            ,so.customerpo AS customerpo
            ,so.email AS email
            ,so.phone AS phone
            ,countryconst.abbreviation AS country
            ,stateconst.code AS STATE
            ,ship.shiptozip AS postalcode
            ,ship.shiptocity AS city
            ,carrierservice.name AS servicename
            ,carrierservice.code AS servicecode
            ,shipcarton.freightweight AS weight
            ,shipcarton.len AS length
            ,shipcarton.height AS height
            ,shipcarton.width AS width
            ,`ship`.`id` AS `shipID`
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`) > 0)
                        THEN substr(`ship`.`shipToAddress`, 1, (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`) - 1))
                    ELSE `ship`.`shipToAddress`
                    END
                ) AS `SHIPTOADDRESS1`
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN (
                            (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`) > 0)
                            AND (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`, (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`) + 1)) = 0)
                            )
                        THEN substr(`ship`.`shipToAddress`, (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`) + 1))
                    WHEN (
                            (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`) > 0)
                            AND (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`, (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`) + 1)) > 0)
                            )
                        THEN substr(`ship`.`shipToAddress`, (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`) + 1), (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`, (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`) + 1)) - (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`) + 1)))
                    ELSE ''
                    END
                ) AS `SHIPTOADDRESS2`
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`, (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`) + 1)) > 0)
                        THEN substr(`ship`.`shipToAddress`, (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`, (locate('\n', `ship`.`shipToAddress`) + 1)) + 1))
                    ELSE ''
                    END
                ) AS `SHIPTOADDRESS3`
        FROM ship
        LEFT JOIN so ON ship.soid = so.id
        LEFT JOIN carrierservice ON ship.carrierserviceid = carrierservice.id
        LEFT JOIN countryconst ON ship.shiptocountryid = countryconst.id
        LEFT JOIN stateconst ON ship.shiptostateid = stateconst.id
        LEFT JOIN shipcarton ON shipcarton.shipid = ship.id
        WHERE ship.statusid IN (
                10
                ,20
                )
        )
```

It supposed to display address seperated by line breaks and it works completely correctly as the select and not the create.

Comment: Through what products do you see the result? Have you compared the select & view through the command line?

Comment: When i run the select it works correctly, when I create the view the its parses differently, i have viewed it from dbvis and also mysql workbench not the command line.